# Make app open to default size with cinnamon desktop, on Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, window, nemo

I am using Linux Mint 19.1, with the Cinnamon desktop.

I am wondering if there is a way to force an application to open the window to a specific size (specifically the **nemo** file manager).

In Cinnamons Windows settings, I can specify where I want new windows to open by default, but I can not specify any sort of rule for how I want it to be sized, which really bothers me.

I commonly snap a nemo instance to the side 50% of the screen, then it really annoys me when I reopen nemo and it is opens in the centre, at half width, full height. This happens because it is remembering the dimensions of the last time it was opened (snapped to the side).

Is there a way that I can force new windows to open, not only at a specific location (centre), but also at a specific dimension or aspect ratio. Or at the very least, don't have new windows for an app remember the old windows dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to its man file, Nemo has a --geometry command line option. Examples noted in the source file https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/src/nemo-main-application.c include:

- nemo --geometry=+100+100
- nemo --geometry=600x400
- nemo --geometry=600x400+100+100

Comment: This worked. I then went to Keyboard > Shortcuts in Cinnamon settings, and added this command as a custom shortcut.